# Learning CBV through navigating method calls

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I'd like to learn about django class based views by seeing the progression of function calls starting from as_view(). I have set_trace() function in wsgi.py as shown here:

```
def tracefunc(frame, event, arg, indent=[0]):
  if event == "call":
      indent[0] += 2
      #framea = sys._getframe( 0 )
      print "-" * indent[0] + "> call function", frame.f_code.co_name, frame.f_code.co_filename 
  elif event == "return":
      print "<" + "-" * indent[0], "exit function", frame.f_code.co_name
      indent[0] -= 2
  return tracefunc

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
sys.settrace(tracefunc)
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

It works well, and I get this output:

```
--------> call function process_request /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py
----------> call function __init__ /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py
------------> call function __init__ /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py
<------------ exit function __init__
------------> call function _newname /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py
<------------ exit function _newname
------------> call function _set_daemon /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py
--------------> call function currentThread /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py
----------------> call function __init__ /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py
------------------> call function _newname /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py
<------------------ exit function _newname
------------------> call function __init__ /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py
--------------------> call function __init__ /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py
<-------------------- exit function __init__
--------------------> call function _set_daemon /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py
<-------------------- exit function _set_daemon
--------------------> call function Event /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py
```

It prints out the function calls, but it does not seem to be going down to the function calls in the django framework. Any ideas why? I was expecting to see as.view() calling get() etc..

Comment: This is not actually related to your question, however,since you want to learn CBVs you *need* to check out the cbv inspector: http://ccbv.co.uk/

Comment: Yes, I use ccbv.co.uk already.

Comment: `as_view` does not really run the view, it returns a function which is executed when a view is called.